# Absolutely positioned element cut off when overflow visible

Tags: html, css

I have a list that can potentially have a scrollbar, inside the list I have list items, each of them has an icon that can become visible upon clicking another icon - but this icon is absolutely positioned, but if I set the 'overflow' property then the icon is getting cut off.

If I don't set the `position: relative` to the `li` element, it works nicely, but obviously if scrollbar is visible, and scrolling up/down the extra icon is stuck at the same position - not scrolling together with the list.

```js
function onClick({ target }) {
  const specialEl = target.closest("li").querySelector(".special");
  const isHidden = specialEl.dataset.hidden === "true";
  specialEl.dataset.hidden = !isHidden;
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".a").forEach((btnEl) => {
    btnEl.addEventListener("click", onClick);
  });
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul {
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 320px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.icon.special {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

li { position: relative; } /* If this is removed, then this is the effect I need, but stuck in 1 position when scrolling */

/* === extra styling === */

.list {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  /* scrollbar-gutter: stable; */
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header, footer { font-weight: bold; margin: 8px; }
footer { font-size: 10px; }

.icon.special {
  background: blue;
}

[data-hidden="true"] { display: none; }

.action {margin-left: auto;}

html { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <header>Short list:</header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Apple</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Pear</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <header>Long list:</header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Gingerbread</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Cookie</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Marzipan</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Cheesecake</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Lollipop</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Jelly</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Caramel</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <footer>
      Lorem ipsum
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not showing the icon on the left instead?

Comment: @TemaniAfif In the real scenario, I have another icon to the left, which I don't want to displace.

Comment: So far, I have something like this https://jsfiddle.net/4chvox19/2/ , I would still want the white space between scrollbar and list to be transparent though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting the blue-icon as a relative ? so it can be side by side to the red-icon ?

check this snippet to find out how it works

```js
function onClick({ target }) {
  const specialEl = target.closest("li").querySelector(".special");
  const isHidden = specialEl.dataset.hidden === "true";
  specialEl.dataset.hidden = !isHidden;
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".a").forEach((btnEl) => {
    btnEl.addEventListener("click", onClick);
  });
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul {
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 320px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.icon.special {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

li { 
  position: relative; /* If this is removed, then this is the effect I need, but stuck in 1 position when scrolling */
  
}
/* === extra styling === */

.list {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  /* scrollbar-gutter: stable; */
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header, footer { font-weight: bold; margin: 8px; }
footer { font-size: 10px; }

.icon.special {
  background: blue;
  position:relative; /* Set the special icon to be relative */
}

[data-hidden="true"] { display: none; }

.action {margin-left: auto;}

html { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <header>Short list:</header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Apple</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Pear</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <header>Long list:</header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Gingerbread</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Cookie</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Marzipan</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Cheesecake</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Lollipop</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Jelly</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Caramel</span>
        <span class="action">
          <i class="a icon"></i>
          <i class="icon special" data-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <footer>
      Lorem ipsum
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I need, I don't want the clicked icon to move places.

Comment: so you need the icon to keep out side the box ?